# Create Access control list in magento 2 sales under sub menu

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I created new menu name Weekly Order name and acl is created but menu is showing if i click the menu it is showing restriction.pls give any solution for acl.xml & menu.xml

Comment: Please share your menu.xml file